# Countdown timer in quiz C#

Tags: c#, timer

I have a small quiz program that requires a timer countdown from 10 to 0, I set my time interval to 1000, what I wanted to achieve is the continuous countdown for every question lets say, question#1 as the user press start timer will begin, it will count down from 10 to 0, if the user did not provide an answer, and the timer count down reaches 0, it will move to question#2 automatically and then start again the countdown from 10 to 0, till the last question.

my code:

```
    public int ii; 
    public frmExam()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     private void frmExam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        timer_quiz.Enabled = false;
        timer_quiz.Interval = 1000;
        ii = 10;
     }

    //button start
     private void bntCON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        timer_quiz.Start();
        Submit(); //---> 1st question 
     }

     //timer will stop as it reach 0 then move to question# 2
     private void timer_quiz_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (ii > 0)
        {
            ii = ii - 1;
            lblCount.Text = "0"+ii.ToString();
        }
        else {

            Submit();
            timer_quiz.Stop();
            lblTym.Visible = true;
        }
     }
```

My problem how do I restart again my count down? If I place timer_quiz.Start(); inside else statement, the question# will move every tick of the of the timer instead of count down.

Comment: What's `ii`? Can't you just reset it back to 10 without stopping anything?

Comment: Just reset your `ii` variable to 10 before calling submit()?...no need to stop the Timer.

Comment: the ii is int i set it to 0

Comment: I'd say it's better to reset `ii` inside `Submit`, so you'll do it even if the question's been answered in time.

Comment: I'll edit first wait.

Comment: @nadia waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa lol it solve hahahaha thanks

Comment: @Idle_Mind :D thanks problem solve i thought I need to stop first the timer then restart again. thanks a lot :D